# .exrc defaults for vi dump a lot on the commandline

Tags: command-line, vi

I specified default parameters for vi in ~/.exrc. Just basic stuff

```
:set ts=4
:set autoindent
```

But now, when I start-up vi, I see a lot of junk printed on the commandline. Any idea how I can do away with that?

PS - The defaults work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .vimrc now. That works perfectly.
For future reference, http://blog.ijun.org/2011/03/ultimate-vim-confiruation-vimrc-sample.html